# Access to the path "/storage/emulated/0/log.txt" is denied only first time when my app is loading

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am generating `txt` file in `Xamarin.forms`. First time when app is executing asking permission and throwing exception in Visual Studio at the same time.

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException
  Message=Access to the path "/storage/emulated/0/log.txt" is denied.
```

From second time from I open the app in mobile, it wont ask permission(as I provided just before crash) and generating txt file. So its working fine.

Why it throwing error in first time execution?

This is my code

```
protected override void OnStart()
{
    base.OnStart();
    if ((int)Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= 23)
    {
        if (CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation) != Permission.Granted)
            RequestPermissions(LocationPermissions, RequestId);
    }
}

public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Permission[] grantResults)
{
    if (requestCode == RequestId)
    {
        if ((grantResults.Length == 1) && (grantResults[0] == (int)Permission.Granted))
        {
            ///Premission granted by user
            string filePath = string.Empty;
            filePath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.ToString();
            var filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(filePath, "log" + ".txt");                  
        }
        else
        {
            ///Permission denied by user
        }
    }
    else
    {
        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

Comment: The filename in your code, `ProductStatusLog`, is not the same as the error msg: `log.txt`

Comment: @SushiHangover - My code is having the updated name only. Still same issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The path you used is external storage.  If you want to use this path in **Xamarin.forms**, you could use the **Dependency service**.

Create an interface IExternalStorage:

```
public interface IExternalStorage
{
    string GetPath();
}
```

The implementation on the Android: Please note `Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory` is deprecated.

```
[assembly:Dependency(typeof(AndroidImplementation))]
namespace App.Droid
{
    public class AndroidImplementation: IExternalStorage
    {
        public string GetPath()
        {
           Context context = Android.App.Application.Context;
           var filePath = context.GetExternalFilesDir("");
           return filePath.Path;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you could use it in Xamarin.Forms:

```
var folderPath = DependencyService.Get<IExternalStorage>(). GetPath();
```

After get the path, you could use the code below to create the file and input some strings.

```
  var filePath = DependencyService.Get<IExternalStorage>().GetPath();
        var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(filePath, "log" + ".txt");
        using (var writer = File.CreateText(path))
        {
            await writer.WriteLineAsync("hello");
        }
   //path:  /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.app5/files/log.txt
```

[image]