# Accessing sdcard/ mountable storage

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Trying to access path to my mountable SD card.
I know for internal is
Var storage=Android.Os.Enviroment.GeyExternalStorage.Path;
Yo access /storage/emulated/0 BT whats the code to access

/storage/externalSd

Answer (score 0):

The SD card is treated by Android as external storage.

After requesting the permissions, you could access to the external storage from the code below.

```
Android.Content.Context.GetExternalFilesDir()
```

MS docs:   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/external-storage?tabs=windows

If you want to use this path in Xamarin.forms, you could use the Dependency service. Check the code in the link below. [Access to the path "/storage/emulated/0/log.txt" is denied only first time when my app is loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67421091/access-to-the-path-storage-emulated-0-log-txt-is-denied-only-first-time-when/67468193#67468193)

Comment: Any update? Have you solved this issue?